# Struggling to get pip in python 3.7.0

Tags: pip

I need pip so I can then install wxpython for a tool, I was given these instructions

"First, in order to get pip working through the proxy, you will need to create a folder called “pip” within the windows AppData/Roaming folder and add the attached pip.ini file. The ini file includes our proxy information and identifies a few python pip servers as trusted hosts. folder path looks like this: 
C:\Users\woodrile\AppData\Roaming\pip

After this is set up, you can test to see if pip is working by attempting to upgrade pip:"

```
python -m pip install –upgrade pip
```

i tried this and got this:

```
   C:\>python -m pip install -upgrade pip

Usage:
  C:\Users\woodrile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  C:\Users\woodrile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  C:\Users\woodrile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  C:\Users\woodrile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  C:\Users\woodrile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: -u
```

if I try to use pip I get:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

any ideas why this happens or how I should fix it? thanks :)

Comment: It's `--upgrade` (note the 2 dashes) or `-U` (1 dash but capital letter).

Comment: @sinoroc thanks that worked